# How can I make perltidy work with Method::Signatures?

Tags: eclipse, perl, code-formatting, method-signature, perl-tidy

I'm using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) combined with [EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org/) to write my Perl code. I configured EPIC to use [Perltidy](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) with "-pbp" ([perl best practices](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/perltidy.html#styles) style) to format my code.

This doesn't work well when using [Method::Signatures](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Method-Signatures/)' [named parameters](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Method-Signatures-20100730/lib/Method/Signatures.pm#Named_parameters). E.g., `func (:$arg1, : $arg2)` is formatted as `func (: $arg1, : $arg2)` which yields an error.

Also, `func` keyword is not recognized like `sub` so indentation is wrong.

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92465/perlcritic-life-after-moose) previous unanswered question and [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=864325) cross post.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the perlcritic script with a pre and post filter. The [changelog](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/ChangeLog.html) provides the following example

```
Perl::Tidy::perltidy(
  prefilter => sub { $_ = $_[0]; s/^method (.*)/sub $1 \#__METHOD/gm; return $_ },
  postfilter => sub { $_ = $_[0]; s/^sub (.*?)\s* \#__METHOD/method $1/gm; return $_ }
);
```

Perlcritic will now treat `method` as a `sub` for purposes of formatting. We can do the same with `func`. I modified my /usr/local/bin/perlcritic to work with `func` as follows:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl  -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if 0; # not running under some shell
package main;

use Perl::Tidy;

my $arg_string = undef;

# give Macs a chance to provide command line parameters
if ($^O =~ /Mac/) {
    $arg_string =
      MacPerl::Ask( 'Please enter @ARGV (-h for help)',
        defined $ARGV[0] ? "\"$ARGV[0]\"" : "" );
}

Perl::Tidy::perltidy(
    argv => $arg_string,
    prefilter => sub { $_ = $_[0]; s/\W\Kfunc\((.*)/sub($1 \#__FUNC/gm; return $_ },
    postfilter => sub { $_ = $_[0]; s/\W\Ksub\((.*?)\s* \#__FUNC/func($1/gm; return $_ }
);
```

Comment: This fixes the method keyword. See this PerlTidy [subclass](http://www.openswartz.com/2010/12/19/perltidy-and-method-happy-together/) to fix with the method signature issue that the OP highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

Perl::Tidy/perltidy does not make use of PPI, it predates PPI by about 9 years (
http://sourceforge.net/projects/perltidy/ says Registered: 2000-12-23 )

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy/META.yml proves that the current release also did not migrate to PPI.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, unless you make `PPI`, which is what Perltidy uses for most of its work, aware of the various signature modules such as `MooseX::Method::Signatures`, `Method::Signatures::Simple`, or `Method::Signatures`.

A reasonable workaround might be to not run Perltidy on all of your code, but only on the chunks of it you've just written and want formatted in some way. That way you can easily skip running it on any method signatures and have it process only the method bodies instead.

Comment: I'm so used to `Alt+Ctrl+F` (autoformat all) and like it. I'll be really sad to give up on it.

Comment: So would I. Though, sadly, the only alternatives I can see are 1) giving up on automatically formatting /all/ of your code without consideration, 2) giving up on parts of method signatures, or 3) doing some work on PPI. Your choice.

Comment: perltidy does NOT use PPI - it has it's own parser

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime a new module exists on CPAN which solves this problems.
It is called [`Perl::Tidy::Sweetened`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Tidy::Sweetened) and offers the script `perltidier`.

It also uses the `prefilter` and `postfilter` hooks of `Perl::Tidy`, but you do not need to take care about that on your own.